# C# Generic recursive struct definitions crash runtime

Tags: c#, .net

The real world problem was much more complex, but I've simplified this down to a very simple test case.  This program crashes trying to instantiate S1.  Is this a compiler bug, a runtime bug, or something too messy to catch?

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not load type 'TestStructCrash.S1' from assembly...
```

In case anyone asks why I was doing this, it had to do with simplifying really messy generics, but trying to post all that here wouldn't be productive.  Fortunately I found a workaround (it works fine for classes, not for structs), so I'm just trying to find out why C# likes it but the runtime doesn't.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new S1();
        s.Bar();

    }
}

public interface IS1
{
    int Foo(int y);
}
public struct S1 : IS1
{
    public static S2<S1> s;
    public int x;

    public int Foo(int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
    public int Bar()
    {
        return s.Bar(this);
    }
}
public struct S2<T>
    where T : IS1
{
    public int y;
    public int Bar(T other)
    {
        return other.Foo(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Funny you should ask. Pretty much the exact same question was just posted a few days ago. See duplicate. Short version is that the current implementation of .NET does not support the cyclical dependency that this sort of type definition requires.